# Homestead exemption

Tags: real-estate, colorado

Colorado has a homestead exemption of $90,000.00. I was served with a motion to avoid judicial lien this last week.The motion stated the exemption amount is $105,000.00. I can not find the increase stated any place. Suggestions on how to find the correct amount?

Answer (score -1):

If the motion states a $105K exemption that is more favorable to you than the $90K exemption, why not just use the motion document itself?

Also, some context may be necessary: various sources online say the exemption is $105K if you (or your spouse) are over 60 or you (or a dependent family member) are disabled. Do either of those apply?

According to [these](http://www.bankruptcylawyer4denver.com/colorado-bankruptcy-exemptions-and-new-bankruptcy-exemption-laws) [pages](http://wholefamilylegal.com/colorado-exemptions-updated-july-2015/), the $15K increase went into effect July 1, 2015.  Both of those pages have phone numbers of CO bankruptcy attorneys who say they'll take your call if you have questions.